# Datatables / JavaScript scope in return function not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatables

I am not very good at js and might missed some basics, but I am not sure why the below code is not working.

For the example, I made mysql table column "address" which contains addresses: https://prnt.sc/yzz18i

I am trying to make a request to https://www.google.com/maps/ for each row

So, if you check the mysql example, every row has different address which I want to act as a link which opens in modal and shows corresponding map where the address part comes from mysql table, like so:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

          $('#googlemaps').on('shown.bs.modal', (function() {

            var mapIsAdded = false;
            var table = $('#userTable').DataTable();
            table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
              var d = this.data();

              if (!mapIsAdded) {
                $('.modal-body').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=apikey&q='+d.address+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="border:0;overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>');
                mapIsAdded = true;
              }
            });
          }));
```

In above code, the console will nicely output all the addresses in that mysql column, but if I put the console log inside the return function then it does nothing at all.

What could be wrong, do I miss something? Thank you so much!

**Original discussion:**
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/66974/put-cell-data-into-url-string/p1?new=1

Comment: You are returning a function that is never called, so the code inside is never executed. If you want to execute the code currently inside the function, don't return anything, and take it out of the function.

Comment: You are right on! Thank you!

Comment: I changed the main code. Only issue i have now is that its missing loop and I am not sure how to do this. Currently every row has the same address (the first address).